# How to create custom object driven from 3 tables in Linq query Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Three tables "Customer", "Employee" and "Student". How can I use linq to create custom object driven by these three tables? "FirstName" and "LastName" are the common fields of three tables.

Comment: You can create a class e.g. 'Person' with these three properties you are saying above and inherit these properties to these tables.

Comment: @Llazar Thanks. It is a linq query, wonder if it works as above.

Comment: You need to test it. My idea was that you can inherit the properties of the type Person to the three classes. There is no need to include the Class or type Person in your query because these properties are derived from Person and are available to these classes.

Comment: I see, your approach is based on the object-oriented concept, I am creating a Linq query running in Entity Framework MVC. I will test my query then.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done to join three tables in a linq query for a custom model.